# How to reduce time between activities in android studio

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-activity, delay

I have an app with 3 activities. I noticed there is a slight delay when going from 1 activity to the next (~0.3sec). My Java code is pretty simple, my XML are a little less simple. My XMLs on average contain: 4 TextView, 1 list view and 4 buttons. I removed the animation effect in the manifests xml. But still i notice this 0.3 sec delay between activities. Is there a way to reduce that delay between activities Or my xmls are simply too heavy?

Comment: What do you mean by "in android studio"? Are you using an emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead of Activities. You can dynamically show them, without delay, because they will be always loaded in a memory. The delay between Activities start is because the system must at first check intent, for other application that can make this action, and after that create new Activity.

Comment: thanks Vadym, I will definitely give it a shot and let you know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Written a code in Run time for 3 activities and try it.